# Savon soap body problem

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

I am using savon 0.9.2 and ruby 1.8.7.
I am trying to make a complex type soap request.

I need to figure out how to code the soap body for the below type of request using ruby and savon. Basically one of the complextypes in the request extends another type and also needs to be encoded as an array.

The soap request object is supposed to look like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:app="http://someurl/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<app:someMethod soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<xyzResReq xsi:type="java:xyzResReq" xmlns:java="java:com.xyz.request">
<somestring xsi:type="xsd:string">abc123</somestring>
<itinerary xsi:type="java1:xyzItinerary" xmlns:java1="java:com.xyz.domain">
<someList xsi:type="java2:List" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]" xmlns:java2="java:language_builtins.util"/>
</itinerary>
</xyzResReq>
</app:someMethod>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

someList is again a complextype in the schema form

```
<xsd:complexType name="someList">
<xsd:complexContent>
<xsd:extension base="stns:someBaseList">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" name="someElement" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:extension>
</xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

and someBaseList defined as

```
<xsd:complexType name="someBaseList"> 
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="baseElement" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

How do I do this in savon.

Answer (score 4):

Savon is based on the assumption that most requests (XML) are simple enough to be abstracted as a Hash. In this complex example, I'd suggest two alternatives:

1. Instead of a Hash, you can use any Ruby object (that's not a Hash) and responds to `to_s`. So you could create an object (or a hierarchy of objects) with a `to_s` method constructing the XML via something like [Builder](http://builder.rubyforge.org/) and pass it to `Savon::SOAP::XML#body=`.

   ```
   class SomeXML
     def self.to_s
       "<some>xml</some>"
     end
   end

   client.request :some_action do
     soap.body = SomeXML
   end
   ```
2. You could also use `Savon::SOAP::XML#xml`, which yields a Builder instance to a given block to construct the XML "on the fly".

   ```
   client.request :some_action do
     soap.xml do |xml|
       xml.person { |b| b.name("Jim"); b.phone("555-1234") }
     end
   end
   ```

Hope that helps! Also, please take a look at [the new Savon Guide](http://savonrb.com).