# Ruby Savon Requests

Tags: ruby, soap, savon

@rubiii has previously shown ([Savon soap body problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267579/savon-soap-body-problem/6270082#6270082)) that you can customize Savon requests with

```
class SomeXML
  def self.to_s
    "<some>xml</some>"
  end
end

client.request :some_action do
  soap.body = SomeXML
end
```

But why would you use a class method like this?  It would seem more likely that you would ask an instance of a class to turn itself into a hash for the request body.  i.e.

```
@instance = SomeClass.new

client.request :some_action do
  soap.body = @instance.to_soap
end
```

However, when I try doing this, @instance variable isn't in 'scope' within the request block.  So I get a can't call method to_soap on nil.  But if instead I use a class method then I can get it to work. i.e.

```
class SomeClass
  @@soap_hash = nil

  def self.soap_hash=(hash)
    @@soap_hash = hash
  end

  def self.soap_hash
    @@soap_hash
  end
end

SomeClass.soap_hash = @instance.to_soap

client.request :some_action do
  soap.body = SomeClass.soap_hash
end
```

I don't get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The class-method example was just that, an example. Feel free to use any object that responds to `to_s`.
2. The block is processed via [instance_eval with delegation](http://www.dcmanges.com/blog/ruby-dsls-instance-eval-with-delegation), which is why you can only use local variables and methods inside the block. If you need to use instance variables, change your block to accept arguments. Savon will notice that you specified arguments and yield those values instead of evaluating the block.

For information about which arguments to specifiy and everything else, [please RTFM](http://savonrb.com) ;)

Comment: I guess my hangup was that the "F***ing Manual" you refer to, describes your second point behaviour in regards to Savon::Client.new.  I didn't assume this is the same for the Savon::Client#request method. Is that method's signature described in the rdoc or something? Anyways, thanks for the input and I did RTFM ;)

Comment: Well, it should be kinda obvious if you read [Executing SOAP Requests](http://savonrb.com/#executing_soap_requests). If you think it's not, please [fork the documentation](https://github.com/rubiii/savonrb.com), fix what's wrong with it and let me know about this. It's open source and I appreciate any support!